# Ember.js Router: How to animate state transitions

Tags: css, animation, ember.js, router

Has somebody found a good way to animate state transitions?

The router immediately removes the view from the DOM. The problem with that is that I can't defer that until the end of the animation. Note: I'm using *v1.0.0-pre.4*.

Comment: Have you considered adding the transition classes to your view through [`Ember.View#willDestroyElement`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_willDestroyElement)?

Comment: fwiw, my answer below about [ember liquid fire](http://ember-animation.github.io/liquid-fire/) is considered the best practice today for this type of situation :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Billy's Billing just released an [Ember module](https://github.com/billysbilling/ember-animated-outlet) that supports animated transitions.

Comment: I am just starting with ember.
The linked page says:
"Things to be aware of: [...] Animations are not executed when transitioning to the same route with a different model. This is due to the way Ember reuses the same DOM element, and will likely not be fixed until animation support lands in Ember core in 1.1."

So my question - is this answer up to date? What is the best option with emper 2.10 to animate routes?

Answer (score 7):

I'll expand on Lesyk's answer. If you need to apply it to multiple views in a DRY way, you can create a customization class like this:

```js
App.CrossfadeView = {
  didInsertElement: function(){
    //called on creation
    this.$().hide().fadeIn(400);
  },
  willDestroyElement: function(){
    //called on destruction
    this.$().slideDown(250);
  }
};
```

And then in your code you apply it on your various view classes. As Ember depends on jQuery you can use pretty much any jQuery animation.

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend(App.CrossfadeView);
App.PostView = Ember.View.extend(App.CrossfadeView);
```

Comment: The end of the first code snippet is wrong, brackets don't match up :) Maybe you could edit that.

Comment: The willDestroyElement animation doesn't work for me (1.0-rc4). It seems that the view is already gone before the animation renders. Do you have a working example?

Comment: Here is an (unfinished) example using that. The animation works tho: http://jsbin.com/imahog/21/edit 

Do note that I'm using rc6 tho, and you were right abut the brackets (fixed it above).

Comment: Thanks. `fadeIn` works indeed, but the `slideDown` in `willDestroyElement` is not visible, at least for me.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is pretty old, but the best solution for this context-specific animation today is probably [ember liquid fire](https://github.com/ember-animation/liquid-fire).

It allows you to do things like this in a transition file:

```
export default function(){
  this.transition(
    this.fromRoute('people.index'),
    this.toRoute('people.detail'),
    this.use('toLeft'),
    this.reverse('toRight')
  );
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Ran into this same requirement on my app.  Tried [Ember Animated Outlet](https://github.com/billysbilling/ember-animated-outlet), but didn't give the granularity I needed (element specific animations).

The solution that worked for me was as follows --

**Change *linkTo* to be an *action***

```
{{#linkTo "todos"}}<button>Todos</button>{{/linkTo}}
```

Becomes...

```
<a href="#/todos" {{action "goToTodos"}}><button>Todos</button></a>
```

**Create Method for goToTodos in current controller**

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    goToTodos: function(){

        // Get Current 'this' (for lack of a better solution, as it's late)
            var holdThis = this;

        // Do Element Specific Animation Here
            $('#something').hide(500, function(){

                // Transition to New Template
                    holdThis.transitionToRoute('todos');

            });

    }
});
```

**Finally -- To animate in elements on the Todos Template, use didInsertElement on the view**

```
App.TodosView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function(){

        // Hide Everything
            this.$().hide();

        // Do Element Specific Animations Here
            $('#something_else').fadeIn(500);

    }
});
```

So far, this is the most elegant solution I've found for element specific animations on transition.  If there is anything better, would love to hear!

Comment: You're not talking about state transitions if you're animating individual elements.  ember-animated-OUTLET is for outlets, which is purportedly different than the OP's use case.  Furthermore, actions break the URL support of the app :-(

Answer (score 4):

I've found another drop-in solution that implements animations in Views: [ember-animate](https://github.com/gigafied/ember-animate)

Example:

```
App.ExampleView = Ember.View.extend({

    willAnimateIn : function () {
        this.$().css("opacity", 0);
    },

    animateIn : function (done) {
        this.$().fadeTo(500, 1, done);
    },

    animateOut : function (done) {
        this.$().fadeTo(500, 0, done);
    }
}
```

Demo: [author's personal website](http://www.gigafied.com/)

Answer (score 1):

```
App.SomeView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
   //called on creation
   this.$().hide().fadeIn(400);
  },
  willDestroyElement: function(){
   //called on destruction
   this.$().slideDown(250)
  }
});
```

Comment: I do know those hooks, however none of those helps me get the job done. The problem is that *didInsertElement* and *willDestroyElement* are specific to that very view.

To make a transition smooth, I'd need to know whether the other view, the one that the router is transitioning to, is ready, then do the animation/transition and then detroy the previous view. So in other words I'm looking for a more *async*-behaviour.