# Ember - animation on parent template's element

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I have a nested route: rent/small

the rent template:

```
Welcome
<p id="slide"> paragraph ...</p>
{{#linkTo rent/small class="button"}}<img src="...">{{/linkTo}}
{{outlet}}
```

I would like that when you click on the button (and the small template is renderized inside the outlet) the "#slide" paragraph becomes hidden by jquery, like:

```
$('#slide).slideUp(300);
```

Then when you go back from the rent/small route to the rent route, the "#slide" paragraph should become visible again, like:

```
$('#slide').slideDown(300);
```

Anyone knows hot to do this?

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521847/ember-js-router-how-to-animate-state-transitions

Comment: They are talking about animating transitions between states... What i need to do is to animate something that is outside view; inside "didInsertedElement" of "RentView", how can i slideUp the "#slide" paragraph (it is not inside the current view's template but in parent's template and i don't know how to select it)